# Basic Authentication not working on WebSphere 7

Tags: java, spring, authentication, websphere-7, spring-batch-admin

I want to add Basic Auth to Spring Batch Admin Console in my webapp.
When I tried to do so on my local Tomcat all is OK. 
Authentication is working correctly. 
Also when I deployed app on my clients Test and Integration environment on WebSphere 7 Basic Auth is working.

But I get Problem on my clients Pre and Live environment. There are also WebSpheres 7 but Basic Auth is not working. I can logged into Batch Admin Console and app do not asked me about Auth Details.

My web.xml conf:

```
 <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Batch Admin</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>batchAdminRole</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <role-name>batchAdminRole</role-name>
</security-role>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>default</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

Is this my configuration Problem or client has something not correctly configured on WS. 
I have to admit that I do not have any access to Pre and Live WS's. Deploy make for us another organisation. But I can asked them for configuration check but now I do not know about what I should to ask.

I have a clue, because on Test and Integration environment there is no https configured, but on Pre and Live SSL is enabled. Can HTTPS cut Basic Auth. info?
When I start my Tomcat with HTTPS configured, Basic Auth is also working localy.

I will be very gratefull for any hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTPS has nothing to do about that. Ask administrator to enable 'Application Security' in addition to 'Administrative security'.